# How do I put this jQuery code in an external .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this jQuery code that works fine when placed between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags of the .HTML file.

- I want to use this JavaScript as external JavaScript instead of internal. Bit  it works only if place the JavaScript at the end before the `</body>` tag.
- If I place the JavaScript within `<head></head>` it is not working also.

So I need help getting this JavaScript code to run externally.

- How do I modify this code when I place it in an external .js file?
- and how do I call the code onLoad?

#### HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
   .blue1 {background: green;}
   .red {background: red;}
   .orange {background: orange;}
   .yellow {background: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2px solid black">/*border*/
<tr>
    <td colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello_blue1">Hello Stack Overflow1</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">
        <p class="Tab-Text-7-aufz_red">Hello Stack Overflow2</p>
        <p class="Tab-Text-7_red">defines red color,that class want to apply 
    to</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello_orange">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
    </td>
     <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <p class="Tab-Text-7_yellow">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript which I want to use as External.js

```
<script>
// convert "Hello_blue" to "blue"
function convertClassName(src) 
{
    return src.replace(/^.*?_/, "");
}

var pTags = document.querySelectorAll("table p");
for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) 
{
     pTags[i].parentNode.className += " " 
         + convertClassName(pTags[i].className);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Off topic, but your class names don't line up with your style block. For instance, there are no classes `blue1`, `red`, `orange` or `yellow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file (in the same folder as your HTML) called for example `script.js`, which contains this:

```
function convertClassName(src) {
    return src.replace(/^.*?_/, "");
}

var pTags = document.querySelectorAll("table p");
for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
    pTags[i].parentNode.className += " " + convertClassName(pTags[i].className);
}
```

And leave this in your HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.blue1 {background: green;}
.red {background: red;}
.orange {background: orange;}
.yellow {background: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="2px solid black">/*border*/
<tr>
    <td colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello_blue1">Hello Stack Overflow1</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">
        <p class="Tab-Text-7-aufz_red">Hello Stack Overflow2</p>
        <p class="Tab-Text-7_red">defines red color,that class want to apply 
    to</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <p class="Hello_orange">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
    </td>
     <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <p class="Tab-Text-7_yellow">Hello Stack Overflow3</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i dont have 6 points buddy,already i tried to accept,but it is giving me a msg

sry buddy,but u have done a great job.

can i have your mail id please I had another issue,but not able to place on this stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can create a new file with .js extension and paste your code in that file. Then just write a code like, `<script type="text/javascript" src="your path"> </script>` in head.

Comment: Generally you are right, but In this case it will not work in the head, as the DOM won't be ready. Of course - the code could be wrapped in a DOM ready handler, but I believe it is simpler to keep it before the closing body tag where possible.

Comment: you are right @vakata,i do tried to keep it inside head or below the starting body tag,but it wont works.

it works only when we place it before </body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Used the "onload" feature and link it to the "body" element.

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

myFunction() will start once the page loads

Or you can use this

```
            $( document ).ready(function() {

                $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {

                    alert( "You clicked !!!" );

                });

            });
```